# The $ \int_Tf(x)g(y)dxdy$ equals?

Tags: definite-integrals

Given two real-valued functions f(x) and g(x) both defined by definition

x  if  x $\in [0,1] $,

0  otherwise.

Let T denote the triangle in the real plane bounded by x axis, y axis and line x+y=2. The $ \int_Tf(x)g(y)dxdy$ equals?

I think it should be simply $\int_0^1 xdx \int_0^1 ydy=\frac{1}{4}$ I want to know if the answer is correct?

Comment: Why do you introduce the function $g$?  Why not keep it simple and integrate $f(x)f(y)$??

Comment: You are integrating over the unit square; you only want the lower-left half.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @ncmathsadist but the square lie within the triangular region.